# Dynamo DB - get only unique values from a table column

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table with 2 columns, user id & book id.

```
userId | bookId |
-----------------------
12     |   3
23     |   4
34     |   2
56     |   1
45     |   4
345    |   1
```

Is there a way to get only the unique values of bookId? like GROUP BY in sql.

Meaning query and get - [1,2,3,4]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't have "columns" like a SQL table. Instead, it has documents (called items in DynamoDB terminology) which are indexed by a key (either simple or composite). And these items have attributes, but for the purposes of retrieval it's useful to imagine the items as being arbitrary payloads.

As such, there are no aggregate query APIs for DynamoDB tables. So you can't ask Dynamo to compute aggregations over multiple items.

If you need to identify unique items in a table you'll have to scan and perform the aggregation in your application. It's useful to think about how you might need to query the data upfront and use secondary indexes, or precompute aggregations as you update the data in your table.